# Class Inheritance With Parameters That Have Defaults

Tags: python-3.x

```
class test(int):
    def __init__(self, x, y=1):#y defaults to 1
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return int.__new__(cls, x+y)

test(2,3)#Is equal to 5
test(2)#Should equal 3 but __new__ (and other defs) ignore y=1.
```

I know you can do this with a normal function, but it is just an example.  However, I need to inherit from a class and I don't like using *args (unless you can convince me to like them..).  So how can I get y to default to some value?

Comment: Do you mean `def __new__(cls, x, y=1):`?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant ^__^ !  I can't believe I didn't think of trying that... thank you.

Comment: @KennyTM: Can you make that an answer?

Comment: Super! Not that it's going to get selected, so it will still show up as "Unanswered" but at least it has an answer now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Put the default parameter on `__new__`.

```
class test(int):
    def __new__(cls, x, y=1):
        ....
```